# Excel - Sum dependent values based on multiple criteria in repeating pattern

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

I'm currently working with a dataset with a fairly unusual setup. I'm trying to sum the number of responses based on the course and question ID for 40k+ entries. Each question is broken into four response categories. I'm trying to sum the number of responses for each question so I can then break down the response percentage per question, per course. In the example below I'm trying to sum 6+1, 5+2, 5+2, 4+3, etc. But I have hundreds of course names, each with question IDs ranging from 1 to 26.

[image: Example]

Comment: Where do you want the output?

Comment: Is the `Q ID` unique enough to use or do we need to include other columns to get a truly unique Key?

Comment: Your best bet is probably a pivot table

Comment: Output can be in the same sheet, just another column. Each course has Q IDs 1 through 26, so it's not truly unique.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to be able to calculate the response percentage per question for my pivot table :/

Comment: You can do that in a pivot table.

Comment: How would I go about that? I haven't been able to figure out how to do that in my existing pivot table

Comment: I don't have time to retype your data, and I can't copy paste a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Scott Craner said, I believe a pivot table would do the trick for you here:

[image: img1]

The percentage column would be another instance of "Resp Cnt", where you show values as a % of Parent Row Total.